# Bootstrap navbar overlapping content when using affix

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want

- A site banner with a navbar below
- The banner to disappear when scrolling down, but the navbar to
  remain fixed

I found this jsfiddle which provides the above solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/541/

Two main points of code:

```
//js
$('#topnavbar').affix({
    offset: {
        top: $('#banner').height()
    }   
});

//css
#topnavbar.affix {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

My problem now is when you scroll down to the point where the 'affix' happens. If you look carefully at that point it kinda jumps, and now the navbar is overlapping the first 4 lines in the paragraph

Any ideas how to get rid of that overlap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to displace the fixed `.navbar` element by adding `padding-top` to the `body` element equal to the height of the fixed element.

You can listen to the [`affix.bs.affix`/`affix-top.bs.affix` events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) and then determine whether the `padding` should be equal to the element's `height` or removed:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/nLjk6amu/) - the jump you were seeing no longer occurs.

```
$('#topnavbar').on('affix.bs.affix affix-top.bs.affix', function (e) {
    var padding = e.type === 'affix' ? $(this).height() : '';
    $('body').css('padding-top', padding);
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Even more overlapping with this padding.

Comment: @Heihachi Thanks for the downvote. You're clearly doing it wrong! It works in the example, and it solved the OP's problem... you can't just copy/paste code from someone else's problem and expect it to work exactly for you.

Answer (score -1):

Add "**z-index:10;**" to your topnavbar.affix class in css.

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index:10;
```

Comment: Won't help that problem at all.