# Bootstrap affix jumps into text

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I know that this question was posted on stack many times,
I'm following this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/namuol/Uaa3U/
I have a problem that affix makes jumps the nav into text. 
 
I have the following code in my directive (angular):

```
changeAffix() {
        var navBar: any = $(this.$element[0].children[0]); // because of affix function $
        navBar.affix({
            offset: {
                top: navBar.offset().top
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: this.$element[0].children[0]]
this.$element[0].children[0] 
css:

```
nav {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
    user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                              supported by Chrome and Opera */
}

.navbar-static-action-bar {
    display: table;
    //margin-bottom: 20px;
    background-color: @action-primary;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 800;
}

.affix {
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Here is a little gif of how the "nav" jumps with affix[image]

Comment: I found this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/29023891/2974568 that randomly works